# Can I change picture of mouse on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, mouse

Is it possible to change picture of mouse on emulator or undisplay arrow

Comment: what do mean by change the picture of mouse on emulator ?? if you want to change the mouse pointer of your system then you can always do this .

Comment: I want to show demo without mouse

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the Android emulator can't do that. You'll probably need to change/hide your mouse cursor system-wide.

Here's how I'm doing it (Mac OS X):

1. Hide the cursor with [Cursorcerer](http://doomlaser.com/cursorcerer-hide-your-cursor-at-will/).
2. Show other picture with [Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com/index.html) (it allows you to use a custom PNG, if you don't like the default bullseye picture).

Both are free. If you use another OS, there should be alternatives out there. Good luck. :)

(**Edit**: Oops, I didn't realise that the question is very old, I hope this doesn't annoy anyone :( )

Comment: Still valid in 2019! Thanks.